# C# wrapper around native C++ class

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, unmanaged

I have three native C++ classes with this relationship:

```
A <- B <- C
```

where `A <- B` means `class B` instantiates and uses pointers to `class A`.

I wish to write a C# wrapper around `class C` so that its functions can be invoked from C#.

My question is do I need write wrappers for `class A` and `class B` as well? Note, classes `A,B,C` are all compiled as a static library in `.lib` file.

Comment: You don't if you don't also expose A and B but it is not clear to me how do you plan to wrap a c++ class into C#. COM, P/Invoke or ?

Comment: You don't need to no, but you will need to create a DLL so that you can P/Invoke it in c# as you can't use a .lib file within c#.

Comment: Mixed mode C++/CLI is designed for this

Comment: P/Invoke for C++?  That's a new one to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, right but then it is not really a C# wrapper. maybe OP really meant .NET wrapper, as many people tend to mix this terms

Comment: @SteveTownsend, sure, you add plain C API for the class and use P/Invoke. ugly, but I have seen things like that. After all it changes `x.Function(a)` to `Function(h, a)`

Comment: The real issue is that it is a static lib

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Often people think they want one thing and in fact another would be better. I'd always choose mixed mode C++/CLI over flattening a C++ class.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic "The real issue is that it is a static lib" Hardly. The C++ linker just eats those.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Sorry I meant C wrapper round the C++ class for P/Invoke. I didn't mention P/Invoking C++.

Comment: That now makes technical sense, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @DavidHeffernan +1 for C++/CLI over flattening. 'static lib issue' meant that he can't add c++/cli or C API to the lib itself as it still would be useless to .net clients until there is also a dll. Personally, I would choose COM interface (ducks and covers)

Comment: Btw something like this would help you I think: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class. The URL is misleading it is for marshalling a C++ class.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic +1 for COM over C++/CLI. P/Invoke is the worst one. C++/CLI is better but requires wrappers. With COM you just write the C++ class (with the help of ATL of course) and use that directly from C#.

Comment: @user1610015, in this case there has to be a wrapper anyway as original classes are already written and reside inside a lib (and I assume that they should not be modified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` can continue to call `B`/`A` directly in native mode.  You only need to handle native/managed interop on the surface area of your class(es) that are called directly from managed code.